# how to get CPU usage of tomcat running in docker container

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, cpu-usage, java-melody

My application setup: 4 docker containers setup by docker-compose: myapplication (tomcat, jersey application), kafka, postgres, zookeeper.

I need to know the CPU usage of tomcat container.

1, I used JavaMeloday to get `% System CPU    93.36`, [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032883/tomcat-performance-monitoring-in-javamelody-and-ab).

2, I used `docker stats <docker id>` to get that `CPU %` is `356%` at the same time with `% System CPU    93.36` by JavaMelody.

In my machine, there are 8 cores. why the numbers in 1 and 2 are different? How to explain them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [moby/moby issue 26711](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26711#issuecomment-248137718):

> 800% is correct here, which is a standard notation for telling that 8 cores are 100% in use.

So 356% means the docker container processes (not just the java Tomcat) uses almost 4 of the 8 cores.

As opposed to Javamelody, used in "[A Step-by-Step Guide to Tomcat Performance Monitoring](https://dzone.com/articles/a-step-by-step-guide-to-tomcat-performance-monitor)", which monitors the Java application through JMX, and reports *more*: from "[Java – monitoring cpu and system load of multi-threaded application via OperatingSystemMXBean](https://bmwieczorek.wordpress.com/2015/11/02/java-monitoring-cpu-and-system-load-of-multi-threaded-application-via-operatingsystemmxbean/)", that value is an aggregate for all cores).

The issue is: docker stats and javamelody don't monitor the activity at exactly the same time, and could report (and aggregate) different activity peaks.

Comment: so, `% System CPU 93.36` means 93.36% of 8 cores OR 93.36% of ONE core in JavaMelody?

Comment: @BAE From what I read, all cores. I have edited the answer accordingly, with a link.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing some performance testings on tomcat. can I trust the figure (93.36%)? I doubt why it is so high.

Comment: @BAE Does it remains high consistently?

Comment: No, when I started using ab (apache bench) to do testings. In this case, it seems that it is reliable?

Comment: @BAE as a snapshot, it is reliable. But, as for any snapshot, it varies in time depending on the activity measured for that snapshot.

Comment: I am still confused. 93.36%  is for tomcat application OR all processes running on my computer?

Comment: @BAE as exlpained in https://bmwieczorek.wordpress.com/2015/11/02/java-monitoring-cpu-and-system-load-of-multi-threaded-application-via-operatingsystemmxbean/, "System CPU" means "for the whole system with range [0.0,1.0] where 0.0 means that all CPUs were idle, 1.0 means that all CPUs were actively running 100% of the observed time".

Comment: I am confused by `whole system`. You mean it is all processes running on my computer?

Comment: @BAE yes, all machine.